Place a className on a React-Icon
I've been trying to place a class directly on an icon so that I could manipulate its shadow. However, neither {card.c_icon && <card.c_icon ClassName="fa"/>} or {createElement(icon, {className: "fa"})} works.
Both of the examples were taken inside a list.map() with an IconType from react-icons.
{card.c_icon && <card.c_icon ClassName="fa"/>}
Error: Type '{ className: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IconBaseProps'.
  Property 'className' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IconBaseProps'.ts(2322)

{createElement(icon, {className: "fa"})} 
Error: No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'ClassName' does not exist in type 'Attributes & IconBaseProps'.ts(2769)

I was expecting to manipulate the style of the icon with my CSS sheet.

can you share the example you are using and also in the first example try this className not use the capital C

You can use CSS Modules to create a scoped CSS class that will only be applied to the specific icon you want to style. Here’s an example:
Create a CSS module file, e.g., Icon.module.css:
.fa {
  /* Your custom styles here */
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

Import the CSS module in your React component:
import styles from './Icon.module.css';

// Inside your list.map()
{card.c_icon && <card.c_icon className={styles.fa}/>}


Using CSS modules wouldn’t help in this case

The problem is on the 'className' that isn't working.
Error: Type '{ className: any; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IconBaseProps'.
Property 'className' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IconBaseProps'.
